# d3.geo with naturalearth map data looks weird on google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, d3.js, geo

I am using naturalearth's geojson 110m/admin0 map with mercator as the projection. In a single-page app.

The map renders fine on IE and Firefox but comes muddled on Chrome. The country boundaries look, well, funny when they are recognizable. The initial rendition is always the same. However, after a couple of div hide/shows and map repaints, it automagically corrects itself and begins to look like the familiar earth. And does not go back to the funny look.

It works fine with naturalearth's 50m/admin0 data.

What am I doing wrong? Is it a Chrome bug?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    #map-here svg {
        border: blue thin dotted;
    }
    #map-here svg .adm-0 {
        stroke: white;
        stroke-width: 1px;
        fill: #ababab;
    }
</style>
<body>
<div id="map-here"></div>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var w = 900, h = 450;
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
        .translate([w / 2, h / 1.6])
        .scale([111]);
var svg = d3.select("#map-here")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);
// get data from https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=424202
d3.csv("data/110m_admin_0_countries.csv", function (error, admin_0) {
    var parsed_data = _.map(_.filter(admin_0, function (d) {
        return d.featurecla === "Adm-0 country";
    }), function (d) {
        delete d.svg_4326;
        delete d.wiki_4326;
        d.json_4326 = JSON.parse(d.json_4326);
        return d;
    });
    var path = d3.geo.path() // actually this is a path-generator function
            .projection(projection);
    var x = svg.selectAll("g")
            .data(parsed_data)
            .enter()
            .append("g");
    x.append("path")
            .classed("adm-0", true)
            .attr("d", function (d) {
                return path(d.json_4326);
            })
});
```

I also tried reversing the coordinates array but got same results. Will appreciate some helpful pointers.

EDIT ----
I have updated the code to include the html and styles. However I am unable to find a pure data URL for the map geojson and unable to put this on jsfiddle :(

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you provide a complete working example that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: @Lars I have included the entire code so it is easy to replicate, however can't find a location to download the map as data - and finding it hard to put the whole data on jsfiddle. If you could possibly suggest a data URL that'll be awesome!

Comment: It's the data I'm after here -- you can put complete examples with data e.g. on https://vida.io/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it works, but if I first center the projection to anything but [0,0] then it renders OK.